# Redirect a user to an external page after successfully authentication instead of to the Service Provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to figure out the best way to customize WSO2IS to perform the desired function.

We use a 3rd party tool (Tools4Ever) for the password recovery of our users. Our primary user store is Active Directory. After a user signs in to website and authenticates using WSO2's local user store as the Identity Provider I would like it to redirect to an external page, the third party tool, if a specific claim is found instead of back to the service provider. For the purpose of this lets just call it "userMustResetPassword".

I have tried testing a custom local authenticator, for proof of concept, that just will redirect the user to an external page to test but it just directs the user to https://localhost/samlsso, even after setting the response.redirecturl to  http://someotherwebsite.com. Am I going about this the right way?

To clarify, the external page/website is not a service provider in WSO2 and would like to jump out of the normal flow of the authentication process if the claim exist and direct the user to website instead of back to the service provider.

Comment: Didn't get your actual requirement. Please correct if I'm wrong. You send the login request to IS. Do the authentication with basic auth. If the user has some claim send the user to a external page to do some work. Get back to IS and return to the service provider. In that case you can use a Post-authentication Handler to achieve the requirement. More information at https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Post-authentication+Handlers+in+Identity+Server

Comment: response.redirecturl will not do anything at that exact place you add it, because the response object you find in the authenticator is just a wrapper object. Actual redirection handles at some other place if you correctly set parameters.